# Seeing the users you set up an alert for in SP 2007

Tags: 2007, alert

We have a requirement as follows. An owner of a site has set up an alert for at least 50 users.  They now want to run some sort of query and/or report that will allow them to monitor that alert. They want to be able to see who is subscribed to that alert and ideally remove them if they have moved to another dept etc. and no longer need alert set. Just seeing who is subscribed to the alert will go a long way. They are indicating that the subscription feature in SP 2001 allowed for this. The alert subscription could be handled as a group rather than individually.

It is my understanding that OOTB this is not possible. Once an alert is assigned to a number of users, that one user can only administer this alert from that point forward. I also know that an owner can delete alerts that are set for individuals.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself, but here is a custom solution: [Display all my alerts](http://www.hezser.de/blog/archive/2007/11/04/display-all-my-alerts.aspx)

However, this web part only shows the alerts for the current user. You would need to download and modify the code to iterate through SPWeb.Alerts instead of SPUser.Alerts and add a column to the grid for the user name.

Comment: +1, not possible out of the box. You'll need to write code or use a third party web part.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft did not provide a solution for this specific need. While James Love is correct in stating that this is completely unsupported as a solution in a production environment, it works. However, I would modify the query to return only distinct useremails as follows:

> Select Distinct UserEmail from ImmediateSubscriptions where AlertTitle
>   = "Your Alert Title"

Answer (score -3):

You can get the list of subscribed users to a particular alert by executing the following SQL query on your Content database

```
Select UserEmail,UserId from ImmedSubscriptions where AlertTitle ='Your Alert Title'
```

Comment: This is a completely unsupported practice for a solution in a production environment.